# Export formatted file TXT from PHP

Tags: php, oracle

So I have the working code like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title> COBA </title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function urlorder(a)
{
    var urlorder="order.php?on="+a;
    var prmpt=window.open(urlorder,"test","left=200,top=150,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=640,height=480");
}
function printorder(a,b)
{
    var urlorder="printorder.php?on="+a+"&nu=2&tgl="+b;
    //var prmpt=window.open(urlorder,"test","left=200,top=150,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=640,height=480");
    window.location = urlorder;
    //alert (urlorder);
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 

<?
//include "ceksession.php";
include 'connect.php';

//ambil tgl val
$q = "select tgl_val from para_info_kntr";
$s = OCIParse($c,$q);
OCIBindByName($s,":bind1",$ltid);
OCIExecute($s,OCI_DEFAULT);
while (OCIFetch($s))
{   
    $tgl=ociresult($s,"TGL_VAL");
    echo $tgl."<br>";
}
$tgl= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tgl));
$tgl= date('d-m-Y'); 

$tgl = $_GET["tgl"];

echo "<div align=\"right\">";
echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location='month.php'\") value=\"HOME\">";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div align=\"center\">";
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"44\">";
echo "<div align=\"center\">PAYMENT LIST</div>";
echo "</td></tr>";

$q = "Select AMOUNT, SERVICES, BILL_NO, ORDER_NUMBER, TOTAL_AMOUNT, to_char(PAY_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as PAY_DATE from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";

$s2=OCIParse($c_slave,$q);
OCIBindByName($s2,":bind1",$ordernumber);
OCIExecute($s2,OCI_DEFAULT);

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "PAY_DATE";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "ORDER_NUMBER";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "AMOUNT";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "SERVICES";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "BILL_NO";
    echo "</td></tr>"; 

while (OCIFetch($s2))
{
    $V_GUEST_FOLIO        = oci_result($s2,'GUEST_FOLIO');
    $V_PAY_DATE           = oci_result($s2,'PAY_DATE');
    $V_ORDER_NUMBER       = oci_result($s2,'ORDER_NUMBER'); 
    $V_AMOUNT             = oci_result($s2,'AMOUNT'); 
    $V_SERVICES           = oci_result($s2,'SERVICES');
    $V_BILL_NO            = oci_result($s2,'BILL_NO');  

    echo "</td><td>"; 

    echo "<a href=\"order.php?on=".$V_ORDER_NUMBER."\">";
    echo $V_PAY_DATE;
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $V_ORDER_NUMBER;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_SERVICES;  
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_BILL_NO;  
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"printorder(".$V_ORDER_NUMBER.",'".$tgl."')\") value=\"PRINT\">";
    echo "</td></tr>";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the result looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want to add the button "SAVE FILE". When the button being pressed, it will export the text (txt) file. The contents of the text file should take from the query (what shown in the table in webpage) and formatted like this:

```
PAY_DATE            |ORDER_NUMBER   |   AMOUNT  |   SERVICES|   BILL_NO     
02/01/2015 08:35:58 |298479         |   130200  |   6510    |   RS01022015001
02/01/2015 08:40:43 |298485         |   25800   |   1290    |   RS01022015002
02/01/2015 08:41:04 |298480         |   239600  |   11980   |   RS01022015003
02/01/2015 08:44:37 |298484         |   269400  |   13470   |   RS01022015004
02/01/2015 08:48:18 |298482         |   286400  |   14320   |   RS01022015005
02/01/2015 09:09:11 |298490         |   417000  |   20850   |   RS01022015006
02/01/2015 09:09:16 |298492         |   49600   |   2480    |   RS01022015007
02/01/2015 09:18:45 |298499         |   119200  |   5960    |   RS01022015011
... until end of file.
```

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: There are several jquery plugin to export html tables. Try google that

Answer (score 0):

Several options.
1) Not familiar with OCI (oracle?), but maybe there is a export function similar to mysql "INTO OUTFILE".

2) You could take the html through javascript some fgrep magic

3) Same as you do now, but instead of using ...
I think the padding is quite awkward in your sample - I will actually ignore that.

```
//first headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = str_pad("PAY_DATE", 20);
$headers[] = str_pad("ORDER_NUMBER", 16);
//etc.
$headers = implode('|', $headers);

//data
$rows = array();
while (OCIFetch($s2))
{
    //this is really similar to what you do
    $V_PAY_DATE = oci_result($s2,'PAY_DATE');
    $V_ORDER_NUMBER = oci_result($s2,'ORDER_NUMBER');
    //but this instead (follow pattern from header-section)
    $datarow = array();
    $datarow[] = str_pad($V_PAY_DATE, 20);
    $datarow[] = str_pad($V_ORDER_NUMBER, 16);
    $rows[] = implode('|', $datarow);
}

$data = $headers . "\n" . implode("\n", $rows);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $data);
```

Beware - NOT tested - I'm typing like a monkey so it's probably full of typo's and syntax errors...

Comment: Ah - now I saw the "oracle"-tag.